# Chrome SyncFileSystem does not maintain sync but throws periodic push notification

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am building a chrome app that uses syncFileSystem to store its data file, allowing sharing between computers etc. My implementation had been working satisfactorily for a while. However it now does not sync properly, instead of connecting I get the following loop of notifications:

```
New service status: temporary_unavailable : Network or temporary service error.
New service status: running : Got push notification for Drive
New service status: temporary_unavailable : Network or temporary service error.
New service status: running : Got push notification for Drive
...
```

The status of the file is always "pending". The "running" service status lasts only for a few seconds.

This continues for ever. I have a valid internet connection and can access google drive through the web interface. I don't understand why it cannot connect, and there seems no way to get further information. This has been continuous for the last week, so its not intermittent.
I also don't understand why I keep getting these "Push" notifications which update the service status to running, but it quickly drops back to temporary_unavailable.

Interestingly, these push notifications apparently keep arriving even after I turn off my internet connection.

In general I find, outside of Googles basic help pages, there is a lack of discussion / support for syncFileSystem, it is something I should be using or should I move to a library implementation or similar?